# Python map values from dictionary to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like as follows:

```
df = 
    key     value
1   Level       1
2   Age        35 
3   Height    180
4   Gender      0
...
```

and a dictionary as follows:

```
my_dict = {
           'Level':{0: 'Low', 1:'Medium', 2:'High'},
           'Gender': {0: 'Female', 1: 'Male'}
          }
```

I want to map from the dictionary to the dataframe and change the 'value' column with its corresponding value in the dictionary such as the output becomes:

```
    key        value
1   Level     Medium
2   Age           35 
3   Height       180
4   Gender    Female
...
```

Its okay for other values in the column become a string as well. How can I achieve this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: The dictionary looks wrong. Is that supposed to be a dict within a dict?

Comment: Corrected it, sorry.

Comment: Please note that dictionary might have many more keys, so manual mapping would not be very feasible.

Answer (score 6):

Check with `replace`

```
out = df.set_index('key').T.replace(my_dict).T.reset_index()
out
Out[27]: 
      key   value
0   Level  Medium
1     Age      35
2  Height     180
3  Gender  Female
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
df.at[1, 'value'] = my_dict['Level'][df.at[1, 'value']]
df.at[4, 'value'] = my_dict['Gender'][df.at[4, 'value']]
```